# Updating network profile

Tags: support, network-profile

Can I update my network profile so that my every account would share same profile as SO. Also my display name is also not changing on **Stack Exchange** main site but any new account will inherit SO profile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. In your user page on SO, go to the "accounts" tab.  At the bottom there is a button to propagate your StackOverflow profile to all StackExchange accounts.

Answer (score 8):

Now the link is called "Update profile info"

[image: Screenshot of the link]

Answer (score 3):

Also you can sync your profiles by going to the StackExchange, on your profile, and press the link `Sync with oldest profile (Stack Overflow)`