# Network profile shows old display name

Tags: support, display-names, network-profile

I changed my network-wide display name some time ago (from "Vikki - formerly Sean" to just "Vikki"), and the new name shows up correctly on my profile pages on the individual Stacks:

[image: Aviation profile, correct displayname]

[image: Meta profile, correct displayname]

[image: QC profile, correct displayname]

However, my network profile still shows the previous name:

[image: network profile, old displayname]

I've already tried updating my network-profile info, as detailed in the answers [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87702/389791), but the outdated displayname still shows up on my network profile.  Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: It worked fine for me about a minute ago, so that's odd. Are you behind a laggy server? Does clearing browser caches help?

Comment: @ARogueAnt.: If the cause of this was SE's servers being laggy, wouldn't _everyone_ be having this problem?

Comment: I honestly don't know, but I'd heard the phrase and thought I'd try it out ;)

Comment: Something similar happened to me before just to realize later that I was copying the info from the wrong site. Are you sure that's not the case here?

Comment: @41686d6564: Aaand it turns out that I hadn't actually updated the network profile itself, even though I thought I had.  >_<

Answer (score 4):

### ...Whoops.

Turns out I *hadn't* updated my network profile after all - I only thought I had.  I'd definitely done the "save and copy changes to all public profiles" thingamajiggy when updating the display name on my individual-Stack profiles, and I *thought* I'd tried the "Update profile info" button on my network profile as well.

Apparently, I hadn't, as doing so fixed the problem:

[image: well, that was anticlimactic]

Protip: hitting "Save and copy changes to all public communities" when updating your profile on an individual Stack propagates the change(s) to all your other individual-Stack profiles, but does *not* update your network profile.  Only the "Update profile info" thingy on the network profile itself can do that!

Comment: Correct. stackexchange.com doesn't qualify as a 'public community', so it's the only site where you have to *pull* the changes rather than *push*. Also, please check your [Area 51 profile](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/189217/sean) which runs on such an old version of the software that you have to update it manually.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Why not allow users to push profile changes to their non-public profile as well as their public ones?

Comment: I don't know. There are/were plans of getting rid of the stackexchange.com profile altogether; perhaps that's why it's still working the way it does.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Thanx for the heads-up regarding my A51 profile - [fixed now.](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/189217/vikki)